# How to Disable http-header "xpowered-by / server" in JBOSS EAP 7.1?

Tags: jboss

How to Disable http-header "xpowered-by / server" in JBOSS 7.1 thRough CLI?

Can anyone explain how to deactivate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove header details using following commands :

> To remove/suppress `x-powered-by-header`

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=x-powered-by-header:remove
```

> To remove/suppress `server-header`

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=server-header:remove
```